# Is it possible to make a for on a NSDictionary object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, for-loop

the question explains it all.

For instance, if I have a NSDictionary like this
first = ("a", "b", "c"),
second = ("d", "e", "f")
third = ("g", "h", "i")

And I'd like to loop on them to make some operations. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it.

```
for (id theKey in theDictionary) {
    id theObject = [[theDictionary objectForKey:theKey] retain];
}
```

Comment: Just as an addition to you solution: If you're only interested in the objects, not the keys you can also use `for (id obj in [theDictionary valueEnumerator]) {...}`.